# MS Access Query won't work in Classic ASP

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

The following works in Access;

```
SELECT Transactions.Date, Transactions.Time, Transactions.Direction,
           Transactions.TransactionNumber, Transactions.TransactionType,
           Transactions.Exception, Exceptions.ExceptionType
FROM Transactions LEFT JOIN Exceptions 
         ON  (Transactions.TransactionNumber = Exceptions.TransactionNumber)
         AND (Transactions.Date = Exceptions.Date) 
         AND (Transactions.TokenNumber = Exceptions.TokenNumber)
WHERE (((Transactions.Date)>=20120803) 
         AND ((Transactions.Direction)=-1) 
         AND ((Exceptions.ExceptionType) Not In (43,44,45,46) 
             OR (Exceptions.ExceptionType) Is Null) 
         AND ((Transactions.TokenNumber)=6605253))
ORDER BY Transactions.Date, Transactions.TransactionNumber;
```

But when done in ASP as below, I get error '80004005'

```
SELECT Transactions.Date, Transactions.Time, Transactions.Direction,
           Transactions.TransactionNumber, Transactions.TransactionType,
           Transactions.Exception, Exceptions.ExceptionType 
FROM Transactions LEFT JOIN Exceptions 
        ON Transactions.TransactionNumber = Exceptions.TransactionNumber 
    AND Transactions.Date = Exceptions.Date 
        AND Transactions.TokenNumber = Exceptions.TokenNumber 
WHERE Transactions.Direction = -1 
        AND (Exceptions.ExceptionType Not In (43,44,45,46) 
            OR Exceptions.ExceptionType Is Null)
        AND Transactions.TokenNumber= 6605253
        AND Transactions.Date >= 20120803 
ORDER BY Transactions.Date, Transactions.TransactionNumber
```

I removed some of the brackets by the way, thinking it would help, but it did not.

Comment: Are you sure it is the query? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306345

Comment: Ah, I think it's something to do with Exception being a reserved word in Access. Remember I had this a few days ago and forgot about it.

Comment: Shouldn't date values be delimited with '#' in Jet queries, e.g. #20120803#?

Comment: 20120803 could not be an MS Access date, it is a number.

Comment: I do not think that Exception being a reserved word is the problem in this case. A reserved word is only a problem when it is not prefixed with the table name. For that matter, date and time are also reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Remou's comment.  80004005 doesn't point at a bad query, I think it points at a data source name being wrong or a corrupt Access file.

I would check your connection string and verify that you can run a simple query before chasing this query.

Comment: I have tested on my local machine, and the query runs in ASP as is.

Comment: I've many other queries in same page which work OK. I've posted the solution to this on the question.

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved by putting the word Exception in square brackets.

Comment: Telling us you had multiple queries on the page the rest of which which were working would have helped in attacking the problem.  More information is good.

Answer (score 1):

MikeY is right.  Make sure all of your IIS proceses have read/write (NTFS) permissions to the folder containing the database.  Typically, that would be the IUSR_[machinename] account.  Depending on which version of IIS you are using, it would be different.  In IIS, have a look at which account the "Anonymous" user is mapped to.

For a quick-check, just set the folder to read/write for "Everyone".  It has to be at the folder level, not just the file, because MSAccess needs to create/destroy a .LDB file for maintaining locks, etc.

Comment: There's no problems with permisisons as I've lots of other queries which access the data OK.